# Change height of row in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have created a simple `UITableView` with a prototype cell and I have to enlarge the height of row. Unfortunately, I cannot achieve that. I just put the custom size of height for the prototype cell in Interface Builder (Xcode) and put method in `ViewController`:

```
-(float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 200.0;
}
```

And `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    AlbumCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"albumCellID"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[AlbumCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"albumCellID"];
    }

    cell.albumTitle.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Simulator returns my table with still small height for rows (ca. 40 px). How can I enlarge the height of a row?

Comment: ISn't it CGFLoat instead of float ?Are the cells dynamic or static ?If you implement this delegate method properly you dont have to set height in the storyboard.

Comment: @Teja Nandamuri... I've changed 'float' to 'CGFloat' but it isn't help. This is dynamic table.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in that method and see if it gets called or not,

Comment: Either you can do this by storyboard just drag the cell height and the way you are doing is right just double check the `delegate` and `datasource` is properly connected of that `tableView`.

Comment: Did you set the table view's data source and delegate?

Comment: @rmaddy... Yes of course. The table show me 16 rows from NSArray but size of height is not good.

Comment: you may need to implement the `-tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` method as well.

Comment: @Teja Nandamuri... I've put breakpoint in that method and it not called...

Comment: You have not set the table's `delegate` property. The rows will appear if you set the `dataSource` but the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method is from the delegate, not the data source.

Comment: @maddy... But I've add in ViewController.h syntax: "@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>"

Comment: But you need to assign something to the `delegate` property.

Comment: Use delegate's method heightForRowAtIndexPath to define the height.